# Android: How to know which contacts already have the app installed?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I'm working at a chat app and I saw a lot of tutorials and answers on how to add a contact or how to search for one. But how do most of the chatting apps know which of your contacts already have the app installed? Can anyone point me to a tutorial or share a piece of code on how to implement an activity that shows you who has the app installed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you mean like whatsapp?

Comment: What is wrong with storing the number on your database and then compare the users' phone numbers list against it? Keep in mind that you should not do this unless you are make in it clear for the end user.

Comment: If you want to store their numbers in a database and compare them you could use this link for help. https://parse.com/questions/android-how-to-know-which-contacts-have-my-application-installed

Comment: Yes like Whatsapp. @Areks in the case of having a lot of users, searching for every contact phone number in the database wouldn't be a challenging task to do every time someone registers? I'm just asking.

Comment: How do you expect an app like WhatsApp to do it? Of course they have some backend which handles pretty much everything. It has a database of all users, handles messages which are being sent, stores information about which users are online and which are offline etc... Everything runs on the backend. The app is just a client to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to save something to identify a single user of your application. That "something" needs to be unique and available from other people phones. Your main (if not only) options are pretty much phone number or email address, or both.

The main disadvantage is that people don't always keep and update the emails on their phone number lists. That is, of course, assuming they store them at all. One option to overcome this could be using the APIs (assuming they have, of course) from their email providers, which, after a successful login by your user, will let you fetch their contact lists. That should be far more accurate than relying on people saving every email address on their contact list.

To "know" when they have "friends" using the application, you will need a backend able to receive the contact lists of that user and check their existence in your database.

In your comments you ask if that is an expensive task in case you have a massive userbase. It certainly could be. But there's hardly other way. And there are certainly ways to optimize the proccess with a well designed database. Also controlling how often you will be performing this lookups.

If at any point you find yourself with scalability problems doing this, it will most likely be the least of your problems. Obviously, a huge userbase requires the adequate infrastructure to keep it running.

Comment: @Areks : i face same issue but as per your logic we have to implement load balancing on server side .